# Mobile provider area code

Tags: ios, phone-number, provider

I am currently working on an app that sends SMS. I should be aware what mobile provider's SIM card is inserted in the device, because this determines the SMS's destination phone number. I was about to check the number saved as "own number", which includes the (mobile provider's) area code at a given location, exactly what I need. However, now I see that beginning with iOS 4, there is no possibility to obtain the own number. Can you help me how to get it?